# What's a good screencast for an introduction to dimensional models and SQL Server Analysis Services?

Tags: business-intelligence, ssas, dimensional-modeling

My team is getting ready to start using SQL Server Analysis Services on our project but none of us have a lot of experience with it. What's a good screencast we can watch to get us started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start here:
http://www.learnmicrosoftbi.com/Videos/tabid/75/Default.aspx

But you have to register for this site.